# Why my app forcecloses when opening AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am having errors with my app. I am trying to use AlertDialog to display "Credits" in app but when I click on the word "credits" the app just forcecloses, why ? Here is my code :

```
 else if (mMergeAdapter.getAdapter(position).equals(
                    mMenuAdapter)) {
                // handle menu items
                switch ((int) mMergeAdapter.getItemId(position)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Browser.this,
                                SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Browser.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Credits");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Coding -> Traabefi ");
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int a) { alertDialog.this.cancel();
                        }});
                        alertDialog.show();
                    case 2:
                        finish();
```

Logcat

09-23 18:48:02.606 30963 30963 D   dalvikvm com.tproductions.Openit             Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-23 18:48:02.806 30963 30963 W   ResourceType com.tproductions.Openit         CREATING STRING CACHE OF 80 bytes
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           Build Date: 04/07/14 Mon
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           Local Branch: au011
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           Remote Branch:
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           Local Patches:
09-23 18:48:02.936 30963 30963 I   Adreno-EGL com.tproductions.Openit           Reconstruct Branch:
09-23 18:48:02.966 30963 30963 D   OpenGLRenderer com.tproductions.Openit       Enabling debug mode 0
09-23 18:48:03.356 30963 30963 I   ActivityManager com.tproductions.Openit      Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42dd99e8 time:88828979
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tproductions.Openit.Browser has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4300d1a8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,662} that was originally added here
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at com.tproductions.Openit.Browser$100000003.onItemClick(Browser.java:340)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
09-23 18:48:09.346 30963 30963 E   WindowManager com.tproductions.Openit        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What did the error log say? That's the key.

Comment: I am using AIDE for android so no logcat

Comment: lol and how you debug your code then?

Comment: Using that. I am coding using my phone

Comment: Do you really want to fall through to the next case in your switch statement and finish your Activity???

Comment: Yeah, there is a button to exit my activity , i am asking for case 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `break;` after the `alertDialog.show();`  The error is happening because the activity is being destroyed but the memory for the dialog is still being occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put a break; after your call to alertDialog.show();

This will prevent you from falling through to case 2 and finishing your Activity which I don't think you intended to do.